# SELECT .... WHERE something equals with Chinese characters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, unicode

In a C# window application, when I do

```
select * from myTable where category = '牛奶'
```

or

```
select * from myTable where category = 'baby牛奶'
```

The result does not return any rows.

But

```
select * from myTable where category = 'baby'
```

This result returns some rows. Could anyone tell me why please?

Note: in myTable, some category of column has some values with `牛奶` or `baby牛奶`, and I have no problems displaying Chinese characters on the window application.

`牛奶` are Chinese characters.

Answer (score 16):

This is not a C# issue, but a SQL one.

Make sure that the passed in SQL string is interpreted as a Unicode string in SQL by prepending it with `N` (SQL Server, [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)):

```
select * from myTable where category = N'牛奶'
```

See [Constants (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx) on MSDN.

> Unicode strings
>
> Unicode strings have a format similar to character strings but are preceded by an N identifier (N stands for National Language in the SQL-92 standard). The N prefix must be uppercase. For example, 'Michél' is a character constant while N'Michél' is a Unicode constant. Unicode constants are interpreted as Unicode data, and are not evaluated by using a code page. Unicode constants do have a collation. This collation primarily controls comparisons and case sensitivity. Unicode constants are assigned the default collation of the current database, unless the COLLATE clause is used to specify a collation. Unicode data is stored by using 2 bytes per character instead of 1 byte per character for character data.

Comment: @gdoron - Not really. C# just happens to be the vehical for the SQL statement.

Comment: @Oded : I have no idea how you figured out OP uses SQLServer. +1 for that

Comment: One day I used Mysql with C#. And now I use C# with Oracle ...  Is it not allowed ? :) Just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

Well putting `N` prefix front of your `Chinese texts` is acceptable. You add this prefix to convert it. However you may want to know that there is a downside to it.

Prefix strings with `N` when they are destined for an `nvarchar(...)` column or parameter. If they are destined for a `varchar(...)` column or parameter, then omit it, otherwise you end up with an **unnecessary conversion.**

Reference: [is there a downside to putting N in front of strings in scripts? Is it considered a "best practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716189/is-there-a-downside-to-putting-n-in-front-of-strings-in-scripts-is-it-considere)

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue today with my Java-MySQL application, and I think it has nothing to do with the programming language, so it can work well in the question's situation. Changing the database connection url from

- jdbc:mysql://foo:3308/bar

to

- jdbc:mysql://foo:3308/bar?characterEncoding=utf8

and everything will work fine.